# Can I use a developer toaken instead of OAuth like in the Python Sample code but for C++?

Tags: c++, oauth, evernote

I'd like to use the developer token that can be seen in the python sample code, but in C++.
Could we also get some C++ sample code? The documentation is very confusing for that language and it doesn't seem to specify a lot of things.

Comment: Please do some actual research of your own. You tagged your question with OAuth, so presumably you already have your eye on a C++ OAuth library? Did you assemble the needed components for a successful OAuth integration? (client id/secret and possibly a redirect URL)

Comment: I don't know anything about OAuth and that's why I wanted to use the developer token instead. I'm planing to do the OAuth part last